# Showing coprime for a product

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be integers. Show that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime
>   and $a$ and $c$ are coprime then $a$ and $bc$ are coprime.

My approach:

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $a$ and $c$ are coprime but $a$ and $bc$ are not coprime. This implies $gcd(a,b)=1$, $gcd(a,c)=1$ and that $\exists$ $d$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$ such that $gcd(a,bc)=d$ where $d>1$. Since $d>1$ then $\exists$ $p$ a prime number such that $p|d$.

We know that $p|d$ and $d|a$, this implies $p|a$. Also, $p|d$ and $d|bc$, this implies $p|bc$. By Euclid's lemma, we have two cases:

Case 1: $p|a$ and $p|b$, this implies $gcd(a,b)\ge p$. Since $p\ne1$, we have contradiction.

Case 2: $p|a$ and $p|c$, this implies $gcd(a,c)\ge p$. Since $p\ne1$, we have contradiction.

Since these cases are collectively exhaustive, then we have contradiction and $a$ and $bc$ must be coprime.

Is this approach sound? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Well...The fact that $d\,|\,bc$ does not imply that $d\,|\,b$ or $d\,|\,c$.  $6$ divides $3\times 4$ for example.  To salvage your argument, you could take a prime $p$ dividing $d$.

Comment: @lulu that's true! Let me edit my approach then.

Comment: Well, coprime means that $a$ and $b$ do not share any prime factors and $a$ and $c$ do not share any prime factors. Thus, $bc$ does not share any prime factors with $a$ and they are coprime. no?

Comment: *A small comment for OP:* Use "proof-verification" tag if you want your proof to be verified, otherwise it will be maked as "duplicate" and will be closed.